# Display property in Python Kivy

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have been watching a tutorial with Kivy and Python about creating a calculator, but I've seen this property: display with the value of the widget id. With this value it can access the other properties of the widget.
Here is the code (.kv file):

```
<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry #this is the display property
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry #with the value of this
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "+"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "-"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "*"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
        Button:
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text)
        Button:
            text: "/"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
```

What is that variable/property? What is it used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to your kv file:

## calc.kv

```
display: entry
```

## main.py

```
display = ObjectProperty(None)
```

*display* - is your variable and it is declared as a Kivy *ObjectProperty*. It is used to reference the *TextInput* child widget instantiated in the kv file. After declaring an ObjectProperty, you hook it up to the child widget created in the kv file e.g. `display: entry`. Once that's done, you can easily reference the TextInput property inside the *calculate* method.

## Example

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
    display = ObjectProperty(None)

    def calculate(self, dt):
        print(self.display.text)


class CalcApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalcApp().run()
```

## calc.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry #this is the display property
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry #with the value of this
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "+"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "-"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "*"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
        Button:
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        Button:
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text)
        Button:
            text: "/"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
```